# WebSphereMQ + Centos 7

Tags: ibm-mq

I try to install WebSphere MQ v8 on Centos 7... I did have no problem instaling the server and test it. When I try to configure client every is OK until I try to put a message at queue with the following command: ./amqsputc queue manager. Here part of the log file.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
08/01/15 13:16:17 - Process(37991.4) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(localhost.localdomain) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.0) QMgr(my.manager)
                    AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION: The inbound channel 'CANAL1' was blocked from address
'127.0.0.1' because the active values of the channel were mapped to a
userid which should be blocked. The active values of the channel were
'MCAUSER(mqm) CLNTUSER(mqm) ADDRESS(localhost)'. ACTION: Contact the
systems administrator, who should examine the channel authentication
records to ensure that the correct settings have been configured. The
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH switch is used to control whether channel
authentication records are used. The command DISPLAY CHLAUTH can be
used to query the channel authentication records.
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1257 ------------------------------------------------------- 
08/01/15 13:16:17 - Process(37991.4) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(localhost.localdomain) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.0) QMgr(my.manager)
                    AMQ9999: Channel 'CANAL1' to host '127.0.0.1' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION: The channel program running under process ID 37991 for
channel 'CANAL1' ended abnormally. The host name is '127.0.0.1'; in
some cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as
'????'. ACTION: Look at previous error messages for the channel
program in the error logs to determine the cause of the failure. Note
that this message can be excluded completely or suppressed by tuning
the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage" attributes under the
"QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be found in the
System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 925 --------------------------------------------------------
```

I appreciate all the help you can give me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to troubleshoot the reasons why you have been blocked by a CHLAUTH rule. There is a blog post on it, [I'm being blocked by CHLAUTH - how can I work out why?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/blocked_by_chlauth_why)

However, I can tell you from here **exactly** which rule is blocking you, it is the default rule which bans remote privileged access, i.e. mqm access from client connections. If you want to have access without being privileged, read [A non-privileged MQ administrator](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/a_non_privileged_mq_administrator), and alternatively if you do want to allow the risky remote access from privileged users, read [CHLAUTH - Allow some privileged admins](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/chlauth_allow_some_privileged_admins)

Answer (score -1):

It's worth noting MQ v8 doesn't support CentOS at all, and hasn't declared support for RHEL 7 either.

http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1350550241693&osPlatform=Linux

At time of writing MQ v8 supports the following Linux distros:

Asianux 3.0
RHEL 6
SLES 11
Ubuntu 12.04

That said, the error 'AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid' you pasted above show that your client is failing the channel authentication checks.

You can check this by disabling channel authentication via the following MQSC command:
'ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)'

There's a good article on developerworks that explains how to work out *why* your connection attempt was blocked you can look at here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/blocked_by_chlauth_why?lang=en

Comment: I am saddened by the advise given here - it is very easy to avoid this error without disabling CHLAUTH as my answer provides

Comment: The answer is to *CHECK* chlauth disabled resolves the problem - not to leave it disabled. There's no evidence that chlauth is the actual route of the problem.